# Can MySQL Query speed depend on the table size?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, char, varchar

I had a table with 3 columns and 23 million rows. Each single row contains a primary key, int value, and a "one single" word, that is it. Each word is 3 characters long. In other words, each word's "Hash Representation" was there. The Table size was 5 GB. This table is well indexed.

Now I am going to create the same table with real words in it, no more 3 character hash. So each word will contain their normal number of letters. Now this table contains 23 million rows, 3 columns. However since the length of the words is more than the 3 character hash, the size of the table is 15 GB. This table is well indexed.

The only difference between these 2 tables is that in first table, the data type of the `Hash` is `char(3)`. Now in the second table, the data type of the "non_hashed_word" is `varchar(20)`.

Now please have a look at the below code, which we ran in our previous table I mentioned. This code runs 0.01 seconds.

```
    SELECT `indexVal`, COUNT(`indexVal`) AS OverlapWords, `UniqueWordCount`, 
(COUNT(`indexVal`)/`UniqueWordCount`) AS SimScore FROM `key_word`WHERE `hashed_word` IN 
('001','01v','0ji','0k9','0vc','0@v','0%d','13#' ,'148' 
,'1e1','1sx','1v$','1@c','1?b','1?k','226','2kl','2ue','2*l','2?4','36h','3au','3us','4d~')
 GROUP BY (`indexVal`) LIMIT 500
```

We are expecting to run the same code in our new table as well.

So my question is, even though the number of rows and the number of columns are same, can our query be sloe because the table size is much larger now? Or maybe because the datatype is `varchar()` now?

Comment: In short, yes. Have you run it with EXPLAIN to see if your indices are being hit correctly? Look also for "using filesort": http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Comment: If you have enough memory for the indices on the second table to fit into memory it will also be fast(ish)

Comment: As you updated that your table is well indexed so assuming hashed_word/nonhashed_word whatever you are using will be indexed. let me know that max. character size of this field and what is ibd size of your table and what is its index size..why you are using limit clause as it should not work here as you are trying to get count with a condition so there is no mean of limit...you can check once removing limit claus..else share the required details.

Comment: @Mihai: RAM? Right now My RAM is 4GB. In my real production the table rows will be 15 billion. But my RAM will be 96GB too.

Comment: @ZafarMalik: Yes. There is a compound index. That is why it search fast. LIMIT is required because this returns millions of rows. You know what happens when it starts returning millions at once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely yes. Use EXPLAIN to get the query plan. Another reasons:

1. limit has to have the whole result set to get the first 500 -> more rows, more data
2. Operations (count, / , etc..) needs to be executed for each row
3. If index exist, this is larger when there is more rows, can be fragmented on the disk

etc....